# How to add required extra fields to Django registration form

Tags: django

I found some similar question but no one never asked how to make it required fields!
I have created a registration form with some extra fields, but I need to force the user to use those fields, and to raise a required error if he leaves it empty

here are my files :

**forms.py**

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name','email', 'password1', 'password2', )
        labels = {
            'username': 'إسم المستخدم',
            'first_name': 'إسمك الحقيقى(سيظهر كأسم البائع)',
            'email': 'البربد الإلكترونى Email',
            'password1': 'كلمة المرور',
            'password2': 'تأكيد كلمة المرور'
```

**views.py**

```
def signup(request):
    current_user = request.user
    all_dress = Item.objects.all()
    all_dress_s = Item.objects.all().filter(dress_special=True)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()

    context = {
            'form': form,
            'all_dress': all_dress,
            'all_dress_s': all_dress_s,
                }
    return render(request, 'fostania/signup.html',context)
```

**signup.html**

```
          <form method="post" align="right">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
      <p>
        {{ field.label_tag }}<br>
        {{ field }}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
          <p style="color: red">{{ error }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
      </p>
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">تسجيــل</button><br>
  بالضغط على تسجيل انت توافق على شروط الإستخدام الخاصة بموقعنا !
  </form>
```

Now I need to make the first_name and email field required for the registration to complete .. how to do that!

Comment: Better way to do this for User is to create custom user model. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Django you can extend Forms by adding new `FormFields`, for example:

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name','email', 'password1', 'password2', )
        ...
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I did already, but what I need to make the frist_name, and Email failed required " Null=False'', need to change the attribute of the default users table!

Comment: Maybe I get your question wrong, but you can do that with every field you want. So you can add `first_name = forms.CharField(required=True)`

Comment: No you get me right, your answer is very useful but it returns an error `AttributeError: module 'django.forms.forms' has no attribute 'CharField'`

Comment: it's a model from `django.forms`, maybe you just imported it wrong [ref](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#charfield)

Comment: `from Django import forms` instead of `from Django.form import forms`

Answer (score 1):

I think you cant overwrite to django default user but you can abstract it

and for required in form you can write widgets and add all html like class id and many more

```
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = {
        'username',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'email',
        'password1',
        'password2',
    }
    widgets = {
        'username':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        'first_name':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'required':'required'}),
        'last_name':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'required':'required'}),
        'email':forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'required':'required'}),
        'password1':forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        'password2':forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
    }
```

Comment: I've just created a full new custom user model and it worked perfectly. http://www.fostania.com/signup/